# Printing only distinct rows from a sql Table

Tags: sql

This was asked to me interview and i am beginner in sql so was unable to solve it. 
we are given a table in which somehow some of the rows are duplicated but now
we only want distinct rows

```
Name id orderNo
----------------
Mark 1 order1
Mark 1 order2
Mark 1 order2
Allen 3 order 2
Allen 3 order 3
Allen 3 order 3
Dennis 5 order 7
Dennis 5 order 9
```

Result

```
Mark 1 order1
Mark 1 order2
Allen 3 order 2
Allen 3 order 3
Dennis 5 order 7
Dennis 5 order 9
```

I answered

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from TableName;
```

but he wanted some other approach

Comment: As the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) suggest, you naturally researched before posting a question here... What did you find, and why didn't it answer your question?

Comment: anything else except SELECT DISTINCT * from TableName;

Comment: "he wanted some other approach". I think you should have started asking why another approach than this would be needed. The only thing worth changing is change `*` to the list of field names.

Comment: in interview after wondering for a while i asked for hint he said you can use group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use **Group by clause** to achieve this. Group the record by all of these column.

```
SELECT Name,id,orderNo
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Name,id,orderNo
```

Answer (score 2):

**DISTINCT** keyword used to select unique records. Following query will help you.

SELECT DISTINCT Name, Id, OrderNo from TableName

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TableName;
```

The above query would work.